# How to use of cast in cakephp query for sorting?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I was facing a problem to sorting data. Sorting was not working perfectly then i do some R&D on it and there is mysql function **"cast"**  that help to enable conversion of values from one data type to another. And it start working for me. But still the question was how i can use the cast in cakephp query builder.I spend lots of time over it, that`s why i post it here to help other to save there time. Below you can check the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the  **"+ 0"**  above the fields name in order array like below. It work for me :)

```
$unit_mix = $this->Unit->find('all', array('conditions' => array('property_id' => $property_id), 'order' => array('Unit.unit_no + 0' => 'ASC')));
```